Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type when referencing component in page.tsx
I have a form 'Userform' and in the page.tsx (next.js) , it references to the userform.However in the page.tsx , it displays error -
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'UserFormProps': dispatch, dataToEdit, toggleModalts(2739)
Page.tsx
export default async function Home() { 
  return (    
    <div>      
      <UserForm/>
)}

Userform.tsx
 interface UserFormProps{
  dispatch: React.Dispatch<Action>;
  dataToEdit: Contact | undefined;
  toggleModal: () => void; 
}
const UserForm: FC<UserFormProps> = ({
  dispatch,
  dataToEdit,
  toggleModal
}) => {
  .....
    }
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit} className='contact-form'>
      {errorMsg && <p className='errorMsg'>{errorMsg}</p>}
      <FormControl fullWidth margin="normal">
        <InputLabel  htmlFor="firstName">First Name</InputLabel >
        <TextField
          className='firstName'
          name='firstName'
          value={contact.firstName}
          type='text'
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
      </FormControl >
      <FormControl fullWidth margin="normal">
      <InputLabel htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</InputLabel>
        <TextField
          className='lastName'
          name='lastName'
          value={contact.lastName}
          type='text'
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
      </FormControl>
      <FormControl fullWidth margin="normal">
      <InputLabel htmlFor="phone">Phone</InputLabel>
        <TextField
          className='phone'
          name='phone'
          value={contact.phone}
          type='number'
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        /> 
      </FormControl>
      {/* <Form.Group controlId='submit'> */}
        <Button variant="contained" type='submit' className='submit-btn'>
          {dataToEdit ? 'Update Contact' : 'Add Contact'}
        </Button>
      {/* </Form.Group> */}
    </form>
  );
};
export default UserForm;


You haven’t passed any props to that component!

The error message indicates that in your Page.tsx file, when using the UserForm component, the props expected by UserForm are not being passed correctly. Specifically, it seems like Page.tsx is not providing the required props (dispatch, dataToEdit, toggleModal) to UserForm.
In Page.tsx, you need to provide these props to UserForm when you use it.
Make sure that these props are defined properly from where you're importing them.

Can you please let me know as what to have in the page.tsx? I am totally new and very confused.
